# unable to display empty view in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to place an empty view when my list is empty in recycler view but it't not working. I tried following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
        initVar();
        initViews();
        loadData();
        if (notifications.isEmpty()){
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

And XML Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/notification_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/empty_iv_notification"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_empty" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see - [image: Empty view showing even though list have data]

Though list have data it still showing empty view. I could not help my self with stackoverflow answer since, all answer i tried  are same and did not work. can anybody help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put below code in loadData() when your data is loaded i mean if your list is empty then below code executed.

```
 if (notifications.isEmpty()){
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Comment: i tried that it work when there is data, (no empty view is shown), but when i add above code in my loadData() function, it do not show empty_view when list is empty. :(

Comment: I can't understand your comment  Can you show me your loadData() ?

Comment: hey set your adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after my code not before

Comment: Sure, i did that too but did not show empty view. :(

Comment: and one more put all these code after for loop not inside loop

Comment: @NabrajKhadka accept it if my answer is helpful for you.

Comment: accepting it in 40 sec .. :D since there is a time limit to accept ans i guess :D

Comment: @NabrajKhadka Well ! keep coding and contact me if any doubt/query disturb you ;)

Comment: Sure brother. Happy Coding :)